# Problem rendering Container with color on Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

In debugging, it doesn't show any error, but the container didn't come out colored just for the Web, as shown in the following image:
[**Container coloring bug**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqglA.png)

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code, can anyone tell me what it could be?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jumil_connect_front/utilities/constants/app_constants.dart';
import '../../widgets/dashboard/header.dart';
import '../../widgets/dashboard/top_menu.dart';

class FilesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String route = '/files';
  const FilesScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<FilesScreen> createState() => _FilesScreenState();
}

class _FilesScreenState extends State<FilesScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
        // const Header(),
        // const SizedBox(
        //   height: 5,
        //   width: double.infinity,
        //   child: Image(
        //     image: AssetImage('assets/images/color_line.png'),
        //     fit: BoxFit.fill,
        //   ),
        // ),
        // const TopMenu(),
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 330,
              height: size.height,
              color: Colors.red
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, what happens if you give the Container a fix height, lets say 300?

Comment: The problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used HTML rendering and the bug came up, apparently it's some canvaskit bug. I don't know if the ideal solution is to change the rendering only, but that's what solved it for me.

Using this command:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me being hot restart. When ever I faced this issue, I follow,

- rebuild the app again or
- `flutter clean` and rebuild the app again

Comment: I tried to do that, but the problem persisted.

Comment: does it happen for all project ? Try to create new project and if the issue still persist.

Comment: I tested it in another project and the problem did not occur. In the project that is giving this bug I noticed that when I switch to another monitor, in another resolution the problem does not appear.

Comment: could be cache or device config issue

Comment: I tried to clear the cache and nothing happened and i tried to copy all dependecies in the new project to test and in the new project the problem does not appear.